# Pass mediaquery as prop in Sveltekit

Tags: javascript, html, css, components, sveltekit

I am trying to create a hamburger menu component that is only visible when the screen size gets small. Typically, I achieve this using CSS media queries with `display: none;`, like this:

```css
<style>

    .hamburger-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1200px) {
        .hamburger-menu {
            display: unset;
        }
    }

</style>
```

However, in this case, I want to set the `max-width` to a variable that I can pass as a prop. My original idea was to use CSS variables like this:

```css
<style>

    :root {
        --screen-size: 1200px;
    }

    .hamburger-menu {
        display: none;
    }

    @media screen and (max-width: var(--screen-size)) {
        .hamburger-menu {
            display: unset;
        }
    }

</style>
```

This would allow me to use style props, but it is not possible to implement this in CSS.

What are my options for solving this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could e.g. create a media query in code and add a class based on that.

Something along the lines of:

```html
<script>
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';

    export let size;
    let small = false;
    
    onMount(() => {
        const query = window.matchMedia(`(max-width: ${size}px)`);
    
        const onChange = () => small = query.matches;
        query.addEventListener('change', onChange);
        onChange();

        return () => query.removeEventListener('change', onChange);
    });
</script>

<div class="hamburger-menu" class:small-screen={small}>...</div>

<style>
  .hamburger-menu:not(.small-screen) { display: none }
</style>
```

[REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/916470d9f05a473f83f703b3077c55e0?version=3.59.1)

(Could also be extracted to an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs#template-syntax-element-directives-use-action) or [store](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store) for more convenient reuse.)

Comment: Thanks this works, i also found that you could use `<svelte:window bind:innerWidth />` to achieve something similar [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/867c433fd36a463fa5bb257cec2c1766?version=3.35.0). Another alternative which i found to be the simplest for what im trying to achieve was to simply wrap the hamburger menu component in a div on the page that i use it. Then hide/display that div with a regular media query.